# What to do if a distribution certificate is expiring for an app store app

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect, developer-program

I have an app in the app store and the distribution profile is about to run out in about a week, but my developer membership doesn't actually  expire till next year.  Do I need to rebuild and re-submit my app with a new certificate?

Answer (score 4):

You can renew the certificate by selecting the certificate and clicking Renew. This means you won't have to resubmit the app just to update the certificate.

Answer (score 3):

The certificate is only required for submitting the app to the store. If you wish to update a new version or another app, you’ll need to renew the certificate in the Member Center.